# Personal Money Movement API

Tags: api, currency, bank

I'm trying to create a simple personal project: I want to give myself bounties for completing tasks that often fester on my todo list. If I complete a task, for example, $5 should automatically move out of my savings account into a discretionary spending debit card.

Are there any APIs or banks that have those APIs that could let me do that? All of the paypal APIs seem to charge a fee, which would be kind of silly if the money is simply moving between accounts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most banks/organisations will charge I suspect as a vast amount of money made by these organisations is from transfer charges. I cannot think of free api that would let you do it.

However you could consider using another commercial organisation, say like Amazon, and perhaps use it's APIs to supply purchase with gift cards automatically? I'm not saying Amazon is free, I'm just using it as an example.

It's not quite what you want but may be acceptable.

Comment: Maybe as an alternative you could just write the program to keep track in a database.  Then every month you could transfer the difference between your account.  This would save having to learn the APIs (unless the point of this is more to learn the API).

Answer (score 1):

it may not be pretty, but you can use curl to do transactions over https, provided your online bank uses standard html forms in some way, but it typicaly takes 3 processes
1.  Login to get a token (user name and password will be required)
2.  Use token to get a cookie (in some cases 1 and 2 are reversed)
3.  use curl to post the form data for your transaction

There are some good pointers on using curl in similar ways here:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html